# apply apriori php to CI

Tags: php, arrays, dataset, associations, apriori

I downloaded apriori algorithm on php from www.vtwo.org but i want to apply it to my CI framework, but the input value won't be called. so it couldn't display the result. is it something wrong on my CI code changes? please help

this is my apriori controller (apriori.php)

```
class Apriori {
private $delimiter   = ','; 
private $minSup      = 2; 
private $minConf     = 50; 

private $rules       = array(); 
private $table       = array(); 
private $allthings   = array();
private $allsups     = array(); 
private $keys        = array(); 
private $freqItmsts  = array();    
private $phase       = 1;

//maxPhase>=2
private $maxPhase    = 20; 

private $fiTime      = 0;
private $arTime      = 0; 

public function setDelimiter($char)
{
   $this->delimiter = $char;
}

public function setMinSup($int)
{
   $this->minSup = $int;
}

public function setMinConf($int)
{
   $this->minConf = $int;
}

public function setMaxScan($int)
{
   $this->maxPhase = $int;
}

public function getDelimiter()
{
   return $this->delimiter;
}

public function getMinSup()
{
   return $this->minSup;
}

public function getMinConf()
{
   return $this->minConf;
}

public function getMaxScan()
{
   return $this->maxPhase;
}

/**
    1. جدول آیتمها را می سازد
    2. کلید دسترسی به هر آیتم را تولید می کند
    3. تمامی آیتمها و تکرار آنها را محاسبه می کند - سطح 1
    توجه: حداقل تکرار محاسبه میشود
**/
private function makeTable($db)
{ 
   $table   = array();
   $array   = array();
   $counter = 1;

   if(!is_array($db))
      {
         $db = file($db);
      }

   $num = count($db);  
   for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) 
      {
         $tmp  = explode($this->delimiter, $db[$i]);
         $num1 = count($tmp);
         $x    = array();
         for($j=0; $j<$num1; $j++) 
            {
               $x = trim($tmp[$j]);
               if($x==='')
                  {
                     continue;
                  }

               if(!isset($this->keys['v->k'][$x]))
                  {
                     $this->keys['v->k'][$x]         = $counter;
                     $this->keys['k->v'][$counter]   = $x;
                     $counter++;
                  } 

               if(!isset($array[$this->keys['v->k'][$x]]))
                  {
                     $array[$this->keys['v->k'][$x]] = 1; 
                     $this->allsups[$this->keys['v->k'][$x]] = 1;                        
                  }
               else
                  {
                     $array[$this->keys['v->k'][$x]]++; 
                     $this->allsups[$this->keys['v->k'][$x]]++;
                  }

               $table[$i][$this->keys['v->k'][$x]] = 1; 
            } 
      }

   $tmp = array();
   foreach($array as $item => $sup) 
      { 
         if($sup>=$this->minSup)
            {

               $tmp[] = array($item);
            }
      }

   $this->allthings[$this->phase] = $tmp;
   $this->table = $table;  
}

/**
    1. مقدار سوپریموم را با توجه به ورودی شناسه آیتمها شمارش می کند
**/
private function scan($arr, $implodeArr = '')
{ 
   $cr = 0;

   if($implodeArr)
      { 
         if(isset($this->allsups[$implodeArr]))
            { 
               return $this->allsups[$implodeArr];
            }
      }
   else
      {
         sort($arr);
         $implodeArr = implode($this->delimiter, $arr);
         if(isset($this->allsups[$implodeArr]))
            { 
              return $this->allsups[$implodeArr];
            }
      } 

   $num  = count($this->table);
   $num1 = count($arr); 
   for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
      {
         $bool = true; 
         for($j=0; $j<$num1; $j++)
            {
               if(!isset($this->table[$i][$arr[$j]]))
                  {
                     $bool = false;
                     break;
                  }
            }

         if($bool)
            {
               $cr++;
            }
      }

   $this->allsups[$implodeArr] = $cr;

  return $cr;
}

/**
    1. ترکیب دو آرایه و حذف مقادیر اضافی
**/
private function combine($arr1, $arr2)
{ 
   $result = array();

   $num  = count($arr1);
   $num1 = count($arr2); 
   for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
      {
         if(!isset($result['k'][$arr1[$i]]))
            {
               $result['v'][] = $arr1[$i];
               $result['k'][$arr1[$i]] = 1;
            }
      }

   for($i=0; $i<$num1; $i++)
      {
         if(!isset($result['k'][$arr2[$i]]))
            {
               $result['v'][] = $arr2[$i];
               $result['k'][$arr2[$i]] = 1;
            }
      }

  return $result['v'];
} 

/**
    1. نام آیتم را با توجه به شناسه آیتم یا آیتمها بر می گرداند
       {1,2,3,4} => {A,B,C,D}
**/
private function realName($arr)
{ 
   $result = ''; 

   $num = count($arr);
   for($j=0; $j<$num; $j++)
      { 
         if($j)
           {
              $result .= $this->delimiter;
           }

         $result .= $this->keys['k->v'][$arr[$j]]; 
      }

  return $result;
}

//1-2=>2-3 : false
//1-2=>5-6 : true
private function checkRule($a, $b)
{ 
   $a_num = count($a); 
   $b_num = count($b); 
   for($i=0; $i<$a_num; $i++) 
      { 
         for($j=0; $j<$b_num; $j++) 
            {
               if($a[$i]==$b[$j])
                  {
                     return false;
                  }
            }
      }

  return true;
} 

private function confidence($sup_a, $sup_ab)
{
    return round(($sup_ab / $sup_a) * 100, 2);
}

private function subsets($items) 
{  
   $result  = array(); 
   $num     = count($items); 
   $members = pow(2, $num); 
   for($i=0; $i<$members; $i++) 
      { 
         $b   = sprintf("%0".$num."b", $i); 
         $tmp = array();  
         for($j=0; $j<$num; $j++) 
            { 
               if($b[$j]=='1') 
                  {  
                     $tmp[] = $items[$j];   
                  }
            } 

         if($tmp)
            { 
               sort($tmp);
               $result[] = $tmp; 
            }  
      } 

  return $result; 
}

/**
    1. آیتم ستهای تکراری را بر می گرداند
**/
private function freqItemsets($db)
{ 
   $this->fiTime = $this->startTimer();  
   $this->makeTable($db);   
   while(1)
      {
         if($this->phase>=$this->maxPhase)
            {
               break;
            }

         $num = count($this->allthings[$this->phase]);
         $cr  = 0;
         for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)  
            {    
               for($j=$i; $j<$num; $j++) 
                  {  
                     if($i==$j)
                        {
                           continue;
                        }

                     $item = $this->combine($this->allthings[$this->phase][$i], $this->allthings[$this->phase][$j]); 
                     sort($item);  
                     $implodeArr = implode($this->delimiter, $item);
                     if(!isset($this->freqItmsts[$implodeArr]))
                        {
                           $sup = $this->scan($item, $implodeArr);
                           if($sup>=$this->minSup)
                              {
                                 $this->allthings[$this->phase+1][] = $item;
                                 $this->freqItmsts[$implodeArr] = 1;
                                 $cr++;
                              }
                        } 
                  }
            }

         if($cr<=1)
            {
               break;
            }

         $this->phase++;  
      } 

   //زیر مجموعه های مربوط به مجموعه های بزرگتر را حذف می کند 
   foreach($this->freqItmsts as $k => $v)
      {
         $arr = explode($this->delimiter, $k);
         $num = count($arr); 
         if($num>=3)
            { 
               $subsets = $this->subsets($arr);  
               $num1    = count($subsets); 
               for($i=0; $i<$num1; $i++)
                  {
                     if(count($subsets[$i])<$num)
                        {
                           unset($this->freqItmsts[implode($this->delimiter, $subsets[$i])]);   
                        } 
                     else
                        {
                           break;
                        }
                  }
            } 
      }

   $this->fiTime = $this->stopTimer($this->fiTime); 
}

/**
    1. قوانین نهایی را با توجه به مقدار حداقل کانفیندس محاسبه می کند
**/
public function process($db)
{
   $checked = $result = array();     

   $this->freqItemsets($db);
   $this->arTime = $this->startTimer();

   foreach($this->freqItmsts as $k => $v)
      { 
         $arr     = explode($this->delimiter, $k); 
         $subsets = $this->subsets($arr);    
         $num     = count($subsets); 
         for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {
               for($j=0; $j<$num; $j++)
                  {
                     if($this->checkRule($subsets[$i], $subsets[$j]))
                        {
                           $n1 = $this->realName($subsets[$i]);
                           $n2 = $this->realName($subsets[$j]);

                           $scan = $this->scan($this->combine($subsets[$i], $subsets[$j]));
                           $c1   = $this->confidence($this->scan($subsets[$i]), $scan);
                           $c2   = $this->confidence($this->scan($subsets[$j]), $scan); 

                           if($c1>=$this->minConf)
                              {
                                 $result[$n1][$n2] = $c1; 
                              }

                           if($c2>=$this->minConf)
                              { 
                                 $result[$n2][$n1] = $c2; 
                              } 

                           $checked[$n1.$this->delimiter.$n2] = 1;
                           $checked[$n2.$this->delimiter.$n1] = 1; 
                        }
                  }
            } 
      }

   $this->arTime = $this->stopTimer($this->arTime); 

  return $this->rules = $result;
}

public function printFreqItemsets()
{
   echo 'Time: '.$this->fiTime.' second(s)<br />===============================================================================<br />';

   foreach($this->freqItmsts as $k => $v)
      {
         $tmp  = '';
         $tmp1 = '';
         $k    = explode($this->delimiter, $k);
         $num  = count($k);
         for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {  
               if($i)
                  {
                     $tmp  .= $this->delimiter.$this->realName($k[$i]);
                     $tmp1 .= $this->delimiter.$k[$i];
                  }
               else
                  {
                     $tmp  = $this->realName($k[$i]);
                     $tmp1 = $k[$i];
                  } 
            }

         echo '{'.$tmp.'} = '.$this->allsups[$tmp1].'<br />'; 
      }
}   

public function saveFreqItemsets($filename)
{
   $content = '';

   foreach($this->freqItmsts as $k => $v)
      {
         $tmp  = '';
         $tmp1 = '';
         $k    = explode($this->delimiter, $k);
         $num  = count($k);
         for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {  
               if($i)
                  {
                     $tmp  .= $this->delimiter.$this->realName($k[$i]);
                     $tmp1 .= $this->delimiter.$k[$i];
                  }
               else
                  {
                     $tmp  = $this->realName($k[$i]);
                     $tmp1 = $k[$i];
                  } 
            }

         $content .= '{'.$tmp.'} = '.$this->allsups[$tmp1]."\n"; 
      }

    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
}

public function getFreqItemsets()
{
   $result = array();

   foreach($this->freqItmsts as $k => $v)
      {
         $tmp        = array();
         $tmp['sup'] = $this->allsups[$k];
         $k          = explode($this->delimiter, $k);
         $num        = count($k);
         for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {  
               $tmp[] = $this->realName($k[$i]); 
            }

         $result[] = $tmp; 
      }

  return $result;
} 

public function printAssociationRules()
{
   echo 'Time: '.$this->arTime.' second(s)<br />===============================================================================<br />';

   foreach($this->rules as $a => $arr)
      {
         foreach($arr as $b => $conf)
            { 
               echo "$a => $b = $conf%<br />";
            }
      }
}

public function saveAssociationRules($filename)
{
    $content = '';

   foreach($this->rules as $a => $arr)
      {
         foreach($arr as $b => $conf)
            { 
               $content .= "$a => $b = $conf%\n"; 
            }
      } 

    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
}

public function getAssociationRules()
{
    return $this->rules;
} 

private function startTimer()
{
   list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
   return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

private function stopTimer($start, $round=2)
{
   $endtime = $this->startTimer()-$start;
   $round   = pow(10, $round);
   return round($endtime*$round)/$round;
}}  ?>
```

my welcome controller (welcome.php)

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    include 'class.apriori.php';

}
// input page
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

// minSup, minConf, maxScan value as input
public function ambilinput() {
    $minSup = $this->input->post('minSup', true);
    $minConf = $this->input->post('minConf', true);
    $maxScan = $this->input->post('maxScan', true);
    redirect("welcome/apriori/$minSup/$minConf/$maxScan");
}

//APRIORI on system
public function apriori($minSup, $minConf, $maxScan) {
    $Apriori = new Apriori();

    $Apriori->setMaxScan($maxScan);
    $Apriori->setMinSup($minSup);
    $Apriori->setMinConf($minConf);
    $Apriori->setDelimiter(',');

    $dataset = array();
    $dataset[] = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
    $dataset[] = array('A', 'D', 'C');
    $dataset[] = array('B', 'C');
    $dataset[] = array('A', 'E', 'C');


    $Apriori->process($dataset);

   echo '<h1>Frequent Itemsets</h1>';
    $Apriori->printFreqItemsets();

    echo '<h3>Frequent Itemsets Array</h3>';
    print_r($Apriori->getFreqItemsets()); 

//Association Rules
    echo '<h1>Association Rules</h1>';
    $Apriori->printAssociationRules();

        echo '<h3>Association Rules Array</h3>';
print_r($Apriori->getAssociationRules()); 
    }

}
```

my view file to input minsup, minconf, and maxScan value
(welcome_message.php)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Input 1</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/ambilinput" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="minSup" placeholder="Minimal Support dalam %"/></br></br>
            <input type="number" name="minConf" placeholder="Minimal Coff dalam %"/></br></br>
            <input type="number" name="maxScan" placeholder="Jumlah Transaksi"/></br></br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Hitung Apriori</button>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: _'It didn't work'_ is not a problem description.

Comment: @HoboSapiens sorry my mistake. i've edited it, is it clear now?